# LiPo battery charger

Tags: arduino-uno, power, battery

Is it possible to build a battery charger with just an arduino UNO board (and perharps some passive components)?. It's a 3.7V 550 mAh LiPo Battery. I understand I need to monitor the charge and the current flowing into the battery to properly (as in *safely*) charge it.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that you are trying to charge from a 5V "USB" source.

If you only want to use a UNO + passive components then the hardware intensive method of application note [AVR146: Lithium-Ion Battery Charging via USB with ATmega16/32U4](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc7801.pdf) which Ignacio suggests does not meet your need. This is a capable charger but the UNO would not be the major part of it.

**"Normal" charger**

The use of any of the available LiIon charger ICs is an easy and low cost way of adding a charger. These ICs and all related components can cost as little as a few dollars. But ...

**UNO + one resistor very low current charger:**

If using a UNO with no external active parts the current drive rating of the UNO pins limits the maximum current able to be provided. If you **really** want to meet your specification you can achieve a few ten's of mA charge using with a UNO and a few resistors (possibly just one.)

**Super simple good capability charger**

But, a good compromise can be achieved using a UNO (or similar) + one transistor plus a few resistors and capacitors. This can achieve all the usual basic capabilities

- Low current "trickle up" for very low voltage cells
- Constant current charge until Vmax is reached
- Constant voltage charge until I_cutoff is reached.
- Terminate and stay active until recharge needed.

I will only outline the basic system here. More can be said as and if required.
The main point of note s that in its simplest form the charger uses a linear charging mode so a modest amount of heat needs to be dissipated in the control transistor. Max power dissipation for a A max charge rate would be 2 Watts when the battery was at 3V and full charge was wanted from 5V in.
Power dissipation = (Vin - Vbattery) x Icharge
Worst case here = (5V - 3V) x 1A = 2 watts.
A buck converter could be used (UNO controlled) if desired.

A transistor Q1 connects Vin to battery

Q1 can be PWM controlled by the Uno.

Battery current is monitored by a small resistor Rcur from B- to ground (or in B+ lead)

Vbattery is monitored with an ADC channel (ADC1 or ADC_V)

Current is measured by measuring voltage across Rcur with an ADC (ADC2 or ADC_I).

If Rcur is from B- to ground then V Rcur = V ADC2. If Rcur is in B+ lead V across Icur = V_ADC2 - V_ADC1.

Q1 on state can be varied by PWM from Uno to control battery current. PWM voltage is smoothed by an RC low pass filter to allow smooth DC control.

**Charging:**

The following steps constitute the standard LiIon charging algorithm implemented by most charger ICs. Variations can be made.

- If Vbat < 3V set Ichg to Itrickle by PWMing Q1 and reading battery current.

  While 3V <= Vbat <= 4.2V chg at Imax for battery.

  When Vbattery = V-max = 4.2V adjust Ichg with PWM to hold Vbat at 4.2V until   Ichg falls to desired fraction of Imax.

  Turn off chg voltage fully and monitor Vbat to restart charge at Vbat = Vrestart - maybe 4.0V or as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. [AVR146](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc7801.pdf) describes how to charge a battery using a ATmega16U4/32U4 (Leonardo), but there is nothing specific to that chip regarding the actual charging, and the serial communication can easily enough be ported to the ATmega328P.